# Data loss while sending image over socket from android client to Java server

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I'm trying to send my image from android client to Java server. Size of image that i'm sending is about 99kb, but server always reads a few kb less, sometimes 98, sometimes 96 and so on. I'd like to know why that data is lost and how can I send image in a proper way. Please help :)

Code:

```
Client(sending image):
    public void sendImage(File file){
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            out.println("Image");
            out.println(file.length());
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            bis.read(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            FilterOutputStream bos = new  FilterOutputStream(os);
            bos.write(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
            bos.flush();
            os.close();
            bis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Server(receiving image):

```
if(input.equals("Image")){
                        input = in.readLine();
                        int fileSize = Integer.parseInt(input);
                        System.out.println("FILESIZE:" +fileSize);
                        byte[] byteArray = new byte[fileSize];
                        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = 
                                new FileOutputStream("filename.jpg");
                        BufferedOutputStream bos = 
                                new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in_);
                        int bytesRead = bis.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                        int current = bytesRead;
                        do {
                                bytesRead = bis.read(byteArray, current,
                                                (byteArray.length - current));
                                if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                                    current += bytesRead;
                                    System.out.println(current);
                                }
                         } while (bytesRead != -1);
                        bos.write(byteArray, 0, current);
                        bos.flush();
                        bos.close();
}
```

**EDIT**
Problem solved, working code is as follows:

Client side:

```
        public void sendImage(File file){
             try {
                    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                            socket.getOutputStream());
                    out.writeChar('I');
                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                    ByteArrayOutputStream ao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    int read = 0;
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    while ((read = dis.read(buf)) > -1) {
                        ao.write(buf, 0, read);
                    }

                    out.writeLong(ao.size());
                    out.write(ao.toByteArray());
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    dis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
```

Server side:

```
                if(input =='I'){
                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                    long length = dis.readLong();
                    File to = new File("filename.jpg");
                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                            new FileOutputStream(to));
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int len, current = 0;
                    System.out.println(length);
                    while ( current != length) {
                        len = dis.read(buffer);
                        dos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        current += len;
                        System.out.println(current);
                    }
                    dis.close();
                    dos.close();
                }
```

Comment: Could it be the way your server is writing the image? Maybe stripping some meta-data or something? Just spit-balling ideas...

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea. Strange thing is, that when i'm sending image with bitmap.compress method (but i don't want to use bitmap) image arrives unharmed.

Comment: I'm wondering if the compressed version may also be stripping it the same way your server 'could' be?

Comment: I see that you reading number of bytes on the server. But you are not writing this number on client. Server reads first portion of image and tries to interpret it as length of data to receive

Comment: uhh, no, I dont'think so :P The image is not really compressed(I think it's not:P) because I'm setting a 100% quality -something like this: compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, 100, stream)

Comment: @EugenMartynov actually I do - out.println(file.length()) - writes size, input = in.readLine(); int fileSize = Integer.parseInt(input); -reads it. Size sent and read is the same on both sides :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my personal experience PrintWriter and Buffers dont work well together..
As buffers trying to read data before you tell it to it can "steal" data that it should not do. For example if you use any kind of buffered reader to read the input on the server side that buffer will steal some parts at the "start" of the incomming image becuase it think's it's just another line. You could always try using DataInputStream and DataOutputStream instead..

Client:

```
public void sendImage(File file) {
    try {
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeChar('I'); // as image,
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        ByteArrayOutputStream ao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int read = 0;
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = dis.read(buf)) > -1) {
            ao.write(buf, 0, read);
        }
        out.writeLong(ao.size());
        out.write(ao.toByteArray());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        dis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Server:

```
// assuming folder structure exists.
public void readImage(Socket s, File to) throws IOException {

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    char c = dis.readChar();
    if (c == 'I') {
        long length = dis.readLong();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(to));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = dis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        dis.close();
        dos.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You're not 'trusting file destination exists'. You're creating it, with 'new FileOutputStream()'. You're only assuming the directory exists.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, in the client side, you will also need a loop for reading the local image, because are you sure that...

```
bis.read(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
```

... is really reading the whole image? So you will also need a loop as in the server side.

Comment: As lipido mentioned, read may not return all the bytes at one shot and you need to check the actual size that is returned. If it is less than what you requested, read again. Basically put the whole read in a loop. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29

Comment: Unfortunately it's not about it. I've checked few times, read method on the client side always returns correct number of bytes.

Comment: Nevertheless you need a loop, and you need the same loop you're using at the other end. The contract of read() is only to transfer one or more bytes. You can't rely on the behaviour you observed.